# Map.get(Item in array list)

Tags: java, arrays, maps

If i have an array of values which are the unique identifiers in a map. How can I use the .get function to get the map value linked to the array list value.

```
 ArrayList clientId = gs.returnSocketID(); //This returns an array (Which are the unique ID's in the Map
 SortedMap<Integer,Integer> clients = gs.returnClientID(); //This returns the map
 storeArray[x][y] = clients.get(clientId); //Try store the value in the 2d array that links to the "unique" id in the map.
```

I can't do this because I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap$Values cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

What would be my approach to doing this?

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < clientId.size(); i++) {
                storeArray[x][y] = clients.get(clientId.get(i));
            }
```

Comment: Go over all values(Which are the unique ID's) of your `ArrayList clientId` in a loop and do get on your `Map` for each of this ids - `clients.get(<id_from_arraylist>)`

Comment: @SergeiSirik do you mean something like what i've added in main post? Because this always sets it to the last value of the loop

Comment: It is really hard to get what you are trying to achieve finally. Do you want to put all the values from the map in your 2D array? Why do you need then 2D array, one dimensional array would be enough for that? What is your `x` and `y` coordinates. Probably, come up with sample values in your ArrayList, Map, and desired output, then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The way Map.get() works is that you pass it a key, and it returns the value associated with the key in that map.  In this case, your keys are Integers, but clientID is an ArrayList.  So you're essentially asking Map to use your ArrayList as a key to return a value from, when it's expecting a single value of type Integer as a key.

Comment: Yes, so what would be my approach to look through each value of the array list then and then get appropriately.

Comment: Presuming that the values stored in `clientId` are of type `Integer` (i.e. this won't work if they're type `int`), you should be able to do something like:

`for(int i = 0; i < clientId.size(); I++){
storeArray[x][y] = clients.get(clientId.get(i));
}`

But again, you'll need to be careful about that `Integer` type.  You may have to do something like `tempVal = new Integer(clientId.get(i)); 
storeArray[x][y] = clients.get(tempVal)` if the values in `clientId` are primitives instead of objects.  Also be careful that storeArray will have to be an array of type `Integer`, not `int`.